# Ignoring files/directory when Exporting Jaggery project as a Deployable Archive

Tags: wso2, jaggery-js, wso2-integration-studio

Our .git directory is causing the zip to be larger than the 100MB size limit imposed by WSO2. I've attempted to add it to the excludes block of zip-descriptor.xml to no avail. I've even attempted to restart WSO2 Developer Studio and re-deploy.

Please Help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to add exclusion as follows to ignore a folder.

```
<exclude>**/.git/</exclude>
```